# How to make plotly ternary plot looks like inverted triangle?

Tags: python, plot, plotly, ternary

I was trying to get a ternary plot to understand diversity in shape of some compounds. When sphere_likeness, rod_likeness and disc_likeness plotted using plotly, it is giving a nice traingular plot showing diversity of all compounds. But conventionally PMI plot of the molecule is plotted as an inverted triangle. Can anyone help me by telling how to invert the triangular plot, which I have obtained after executing following command. Thank you..

`df.head(5)`

```
    smiles  npr1    npr2    sphere_likeness     rod_likeness    disc_likeness
0   ClCC(Cl)(Cl)Cl  0.541834    0.936058    0.477893    0.127884    3.942238e-01
1   CC(Cl)(Cl)Cl    0.718463    0.718463    0.436926    0.563074    1.141665e-07
2   ClC(Cl)C(Cl)Cl  0.519768    0.841920    0.361688    0.316160    3.221519e-01
3   ClCC(Cl)Cl  0.498890    0.694875    0.193765    0.610249    1.959857e-01
4   FC(F)(Cl)C(F)(Cl)Cl     0.720879    0.944308    0.665187    0.111383    2.234296e-01
```

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter_ternary(df, a="sphere_likeness", b="rod_likeness", c="disc_likeness")

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def makeAxis(title, tickangle=0, tickprefix='', ticksuffix='', tickformat=''):
    ''' all-in-one axis customizer '''
    return {
      'title': title,
      'titlefont': { 'size': 20 },
      'tickangle': tickangle,
      'tickfont': { 'size': 15 },
      'tickcolor': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
      'tickformat': tickformat,
      'showticklabels': True,
      'showtickprefix': 'all',
      'tickprefix': tickprefix,
      'showticksuffix': 'all',
      'ticksuffix': ticksuffix,
      'ticklen': 5,
      'showline': True,
      'showgrid': True
    }

# Construct a dataframe from ASCII strings
pmi_text = ["    smiles  npr1    npr2    sphere_likeness     rod_likeness    disc_likeness",
            "0   ClCC(Cl)(Cl)Cl  0.541834    0.936058    0.477893    0.127884    3.942238e-01",
            "1   CC(Cl)(Cl)Cl    0.718463    0.718463    0.436926    0.563074    1.141665e-07",
            "2   ClC(Cl)C(Cl)Cl  0.519768    0.841920    0.361688    0.316160    3.221519e-01",
            "3   ClCC(Cl)Cl  0.498890    0.694875    0.193765    0.610249    1.959857e-01",
            "4   FC(F)(Cl)C(F)(Cl)Cl     0.720879    0.944308    0.665187    0.111383    2.234296e-01"]
t_smiles, t_npr1, t_npr2 = 'smiles', 'npr1', 'npr2'
data_raw = dict(zip(pmi_text[0][4:].split(), np.array([r[4:].split() for r in pmi_text[1:]]).T))
data_pmi = {k: (v if k == t_smiles else np.asfarray(v)) for k, v in data_raw.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_pmi)
mat_customdata = np.stack((df[t_npr1], df[t_npr2]), axis=-1)
display(df)

t_A, t_B, t_C, t_suffix = 'rod', 'disc', 'sphere', '_likeness'
trace_name, figure_title = 'PMI', 'Principal Moments of Inertia'
fig = go.Figure( go.Scatterternary(  
    name=trace_name,
    text=df[t_smiles],
    a=df[f'{t_A}{t_suffix}'],
    b=df[f'{t_B}{t_suffix}'],
    c=df[f'{t_C}{t_suffix}'],
    customdata=mat_customdata,
    hoverlabel_align='right',
    hovertemplate = "".join(['<b>%{text}:</b><br><br>',
                             t_A + ': %{a:.6f}<br>',
                             t_B + ': %{b:.6f}<br>',
                             t_C + ': %{c:.6f}<br><br>',
                             t_npr1 + ': %{customdata[0]:g}<br>',
                             t_npr2 + ': %{customdata[1]:g}',
                             '<extra></extra>']), 
    mode='markers',
    marker={'size': 12} 
))

fig.update_layout({
    'title': figure_title,
    'ternary':
        {
        'sum': 1,
        'aaxis': makeAxis(t_A.upper() + '      .',   # '.' is for sake of alignment
                          tickprefix='r=',
                          tickformat='.2f'),
        'baxis': makeAxis(t_B.upper() + '      .', 
                          tickangle=60, 
                          tickprefix='d=',
                          tickformat='.2f'),
        'caxis': makeAxis('.           ' + t_C.upper(), 
                          tickangle=-60, 
                          tickprefix='s=',
                          tickformat='.2f'),
    },
    'showlegend': False
})
fig.show()
```

Comment: In the above code, I created a ternary plot that puts the ordering of the vertices (the chirality of the names) in a conventional order for PMI plots.

I looked into using a matplotlib Affine2D() transform to rotate the contents of the entire figure, but (alas) I could only figure out how to do that for a matplotlib axes (ax) object, not for a figure (fig) object.

None of the workarounds I can think of are elegant.   You could screenshot the graph above, then rotate and crop the screenshot.   You could write a ternary plot without labels to a bitmap file and mirror the bitmap.